# How to set Time-picker in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, bootstrap-timepicker

I need to create a view that includes a field with time only. Can anyone help me on how to create `Timepicker` in MVC 4 razor.

This is my code:

**Model**

```
public TimeSpan TIME_OUT { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TIME_OUT, "End Time", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4" })
     <div class='input-group date col-xs-8 col-sm-6' id='timeout'>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TIME_OUT, new { @class = "form-control" })
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
              </span>
          </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#timeout').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
 });
```

This is the result of my code:

[image: Timepicker]

But when I click the time icon, it doesn't show the result I want

This is what I want to do in my timepicker

[image: bootstrap timepicker]

Comment: so the problem is that this format still shows the date aspect, and not just time?

Comment: I have tested your code and it does work for me, so what *exactly* is your issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to exactly which `datetimepicker` add-on you're using.

Comment: @freedomn-m - **bootstrap-datepicker.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker.css** these are the js and css i've used in my application.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid - I've use datatype TimeSpan in my model, In my view. I want to display a timepicker. I will edit my question, just to show you what I want to do.

Comment: @freedomn-m - I used **bootstrap v3.3.6 and bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker v 4.15.35.1**

Comment: @KimJean a TimeSpan is a difference in time (eg 1hour) not a time of day.  Have a look at the output HTML to see `input type='x'` where x should be 'text' (from the bootstrap help page and your should-be example).  Try changing the type to different things (start with just string).

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap time picker, and set it by this Jquery

```
$("#YourId").timepicker("setTime", '');
```

Refer this Bootstrap Timpicker examples,

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

[responsive-bootstrap-3-timepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033746/responsive-bootstrap-3-timepicker)

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Or OP could use any of 1000 other *better* time pickers... but the question does not mention wanting to add the excessive overhead that the incompatible bootstrap adds to jquery-ui in *mvc 4*.

Comment: OP is mention the Bootstrap-timepicker in the Tag was removed by me for the more better answers

Comment: Strange - why did you remove the tag?   Either way, it should be in the question text, not rely on tags.

Comment: `Bootstrap-timepicker` is not well-known tag to be appear in the list, as i think so, was i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Given the plethora of other tags in the pre-edit, it was most likely chosen because it had 'timepicker' rather than be relevant to the question.  Your edit was approved, so others agreed with the edit (as I would have FYI), so nothing wrong - need to wait for OP to answer my question as to exactly which datetimepicker they are using.